# Laravel dusk selector, how to use :first An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Tags: selenium, laravel-dusk

I have elements in a page as follows:

```
<input name="birth_date" autocomplete="off" value="12/09/2022">
<input name="birth_date" autocomplete="off" value="12/09/2022">
```

and I want to enter data on the first element with that name.

I would like to avoid xpath.

I have tried:

```
$browser->type('input[name=\'birth_date\']:first','12/10/2022');
$browser->type("input[name='birth_date']:first",'12/10/2022');
```

but keep getting invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this selector:

```
input[name="birth_date"]:first-of-type
```

With your code could be something like:

```
$browser->type('input[name="birth_date"]:first-of-type','12/10/2022');
```